# SQL Server - How to switch between 2 possible SELECT statements

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, select, case-statement

I would like to use a parameter in my mssql stored procedures to switch between a small and a detailed result (for maintainability, performance and network load reasons).

If parameter is set to 1 i get all columns, else only the one or two most important.
In a very limited way it works like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllUsers]
 @detail BIT
AS
 IF @detail = 1 SELECT UserName, Title, UserID FROM Users
 ELSE SELECT Username FROM Users
```

But I want to use a combined WHEN clause.
The following is what i tried, but this doesnt work.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllUsers]
 @detail BIT
AS
 CASE @detail
    WHEN 1 THEN SELECT UserName, Title, UserID
    ELSE SELECT UserName END
    FROM Users
    WHERE UserID < 5
```

Is there any way to achieve somehting like that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it is terrible API design to have a stored procedure return different record types based on an input variable. I think you should create two stored procedure, `GetAllUsers` and `GetAllUsersWithDetails`.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I would use two different stored procedures.  There is no reason to create a complex implementation simply to force things to fit inside one stored procedure.

Comment: I also thought about this. So I think I will just put it in two.
One reason would be, that a change in the where clause would effect the small and the detailed version. I expect the where clause to get big and without such a 'trick' I have two big where clauses that are exactly the same in 2 stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree witht [klausbyskov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691238/mssql-how-to-switch-between-2-possible-select-satements/2691281#2691281) that two procedures are a better design, I will try to answer your question anyway - and I am afraid that the short answer is **no**.

It is indeed possible to execute two different *select statements* (which is what you have in your first code sample) depending on the value of a variable, but it is not possible to alter the *projection* inside a single select statement this way.